# Is there a native graph database extension for MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to store some kind of my relational data into graphs. There are two options:

- Parent/Child
- Nested Sets

Where Nested Sets are only useful for hierachical data, the Parent/Child model has a huge impact on performance, especially when querying large sets of nodes.

I noticed, that MariaDB has a storage engine called OQGRAPH: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/oqgraph-storage-engine/
which seems to look as the best implementation of graphs for RDBMS.

Are there more options known, or should I use Recursive Common Table Expressions (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/)

Answer (score 1):

While there are Recursive CTEs and OQGraph, using a graph database will give you better syntax to use around queries and performance optimized for those forms of queries.